# PIMCORE from excel to populate map

Tags: csv, dictionary, import, geolocation, pimcore

Can someone tell me the correct format (CSV or other, from excel) to populate a map in pimcore?
Bulk import.

I would like to create this file to allow my web agency to populate default data with pins (10000) on a map.
The point will geolocate the address with a "name", the address, and 2 other data.

I want to know what is to be divided in the field?

Ex : name ; street ; nr ; PC ; city ; data1 ; data2 (corresponding to excel field)

I'm a newbie in Pimcore... but the csv with excel could be ok for me ;o))

thanks for yr help

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a CSV. On CSV import you can map each column of the CSV to the corresponding field in the pimcore object. Use the column configuration. Further information can be found in the docs here: https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/current/User_Documentation/DataObjects/CSV_Import/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok thank you Cruiser.

Any idea how to split the address for Pimcore ?

Street - nr - city - PC ?
So, my question is more how to format my excel sheet for the csv to Pimcore:

- Streets
- Numbers
- Post codes
- City

How Pimcore read the address structure ?
I could be stupid as question but transform 10000 addresses is a bit for formula work...